# SSDT database project - set external table data source using SQLCMD variables

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, sqlcmd

I have created a Azure SQL database project in VS.  My stored procedures have to reference tables in another Azure SQL database.  So I have defined an external data source, as shown below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE CRM_UAT  
WITH (   
    TYPE = RDBMS,  
    LOCATION = 'blah.database.windows.net',  
    DATABASE_NAME = 'crm-uat',  
    CREDENTIAL = CRM_UAT_CRMUser 
);
```

I have then defined my external tables to reference this external data source, as shown below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[venue] (  
    Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(100) NULL
)
WITH (  
    DATA_SOURCE = CRM_UAT  
);
```

Now that I am wanting to deploy my solution to UAT as well as PROD, I am trying to parameterise the data source reference in my external table definition.

So, in my project, under properties, i have created a SQLCMD variable called $(DataSource).  I have then change the definition of my external table to be as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[venue] (  
    Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(100) NULL
)
WITH (  
    DATA_SOURCE = [$(DataSource)]
);
```

I have created 2 publish profiles, one for UAT and one for PROD.  The issue is that I cant get my project to build now, it keeps throwing the error:

```
"Error      SQL71501: SqlExternalTable: [dbo].[venue] has an unresolved reference to SqlExternalDataSource [$(DataSource)]".
```

Okay, so its trying to parse my script but does not like it.  So I have tried to change my scripts BuildAction to 'none' and then call the script from my pre-deployment script but again the project wont build and it throws the below error.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'.
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 4, Line 28
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. 
Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
```

That really surprised me as I thought if you set it to 'none', it does not try to parse or build it and only when it is creating the publish script will it substitute the required value in and then on trying to execute it would throw an error if there was one.

I have read so many posts but no-one seems to have encountered this issue, maybe Im going about it all wrong?

Many thanks in advance for your answers